# Matplotlib figure displaying differently in PyCharm vs once packaged

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, package

I am writing a [Python package](https://test.pypi.org/project/geostates/0.1.2.8/) that contains a function that creates a plot of the United States. I initially wrote the code in PyCharm. Once I package the project, upload it to the TestPyPI repo, and then install it and run it in a Jupyter notebook locally I get a very different output than when I run/test it in PyCharm. The code is the same for each so I am guessing this might have something to do with how they plots are being displayed in different environments?

When I run this code in **PyCharm** (using `plt.show()` for testing):

```
from geostates.shapefiles import load_states
from geostates.plot import plot_states

df = load_states()

plot_states(df, column='STATEFP', extra_regions=True, labels='both', cmap='copper_r')
```

I get this output:

[image]

However when I run this same code in a **Jupyter notebook** I first import the package from TestPyPI using:

```
%pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ geostates==0.1.2.8
```

I then run the same code:

```
from geostates.shapefiles import load_states
from geostates.plot import plot_states

df = load_states()

plot_states(df, column='STATEFP', extra_regions=True, labels='both', cmap='copper_r');
```

I get this output:

[image]

As you can see, there is a **significant amount of stretching** that distorts the figure once it is output despite the fact that the function is using the same code. **How can I fix this/why is this occurring?**

The code that is originally used to construct the figure (containing all of the inset axes) is:

```
fig, continental_states_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

# create an axis with two insets
alaska_ax = continental_states_ax.inset_axes([.08, .012, .20, .28])
hawaii_ax = continental_states_ax.inset_axes([.28, .014, .15, .19])

# create two inset plots for the extra regions
puerto_rico_ax = continental_states_ax.inset_axes([.512, .03, .11, .11])
guam_ax = continental_states_ax.inset_axes([.612, .03, .10, .15])
```

So this suggests that the `[x, y, height, width]` coordinates for the inset axis for Alaska and Hawaii is (for the y coordinate) `.012` and `.014` respectively. This makes sense and consequently explains the small height variation in the figure output in PyCharm. I am a little confused however why this seems to get so distorted for the Jupyter notebook output.

Any links to helpful resources such as documentation, tutorial, or examples would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am using these added magic functions in Jupyter for the rendering of my figures:

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

**EDIT 2:**

Interestingly, too, despite having set the axis to be off, they are also showing up in the figure inside of the Jupyter notebook output.

Comment: the display of images rendered inline by pycharm and jupyterlab are heavily dependent on the matplotlib configuration *for those environments*. Have you considered trying to run the code from source using jupyterlab, or installing your distribution and opening it in pycharm? I doubt this is a packaging issue.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you for your response. I guess my expectation is that it would likely render "correctly" if I do this. However - I am trying to make it so that it is compatible across various environments so that you can use it right inside of a Jupyter notebook or inside of PyCharm and, more or less, get the same result.

Comment: generally, best practices would be to provide an extension library which sets up plots for users but doesn't override their settings. I think a library like cartopy does a good job striking this balance - it necessarily manipulates axes objects pretty dramatically, as this is required for the spatial transforms, but other than this it leaves the user's style preferences alone. in that way, you can use cartopy with matplotlib or seaborn style themes and everything works as expected.

Comment: that said, if your primary concern is with the aspect ratio of the maps, you could enforce a certain aspect ratio, or actually use cartopy :)

Comment: Have you made sure that you are using the same projection / CRS for your shapefiles in testing vs. in the notebook? The second map looks suspiciously like it's in WGS84, with more stretching for more northerly latitudes. You might have reprojected at some point in dev and forgot about having done so!